# how many possible combinations are there of 4 red balls and 4 blue balls on a 16 square board?

Tags: probability, statistics

I originally got (16!)/(8!) by thinking that the first ball would have 16 possible squares, the next 15, and so on, but that doesn't account for some of the balls being the same color. For this question assume that symmetrical boards are different. How many possible board combinations are there?

Comment: Are all arrangements distinct or do the symmetries matter?  For instance, if two patterns differ only by a rotation, are they different?

Comment: @lulu updated the question to make that clear

Comment: Well, how many ways can you place the red ones?  Forget about the blue for now.  I am assuming that a square can hold no balls or exactly one, not more.

Comment: @lulu 1820 because of combination I think (16!)/((12!)*(4!))

Comment: Sure, it's the binomial symbol $\binom {16}{4}$.  Now, having done that, how many ways can you place the $4$ blue ones?

Comment: @lulu oh ok so it's $\binom{16}{4} * \binom{12}{4}$ I think. Thanks for the help

Comment: There you go. $\quad $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149618/discussion-between-ekadh-singh-reinstate-monica-and-lulu).

Comment: You may expand your $\binom{16}{4} \binom{12}{4}$ into a fraction of factorials, cancel the $12!$, and compare the result with your original guess $(16!)/(8!)$. You might notice a combinatorial explanation for the ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is $900900$

There are 1820 ways to put 4 red balls on the board, becuase $\binom{16}{4}=1820$ selects 4 squares to put red balls on out of the 16 squares on the grid.

Each of the 1820 boards has 12 remaining squares to put the blue balls on, and doing $\binom{12}{4}=495$ gives the amount of ways the blue balls can go on each of the 1820 boards.

Therefore, to find the total amount of boards, 1820*495 gives 900900, which is the answer

The originals guess was $(4!)*(4!)$ times too large, likely due to not accounting for there being 4 red balls and there being 4 blue balls. (I'm unsure about the reason part)

Credit for this answer goes to lulu and peterwhy, who told me how to solve it in the comments.